# same class div sum , display in div and read $variable on php

Tags: php, jquery

I want to sum all numbers in the same div class (class is dinamic variable called $events[2])  and display it on my class div result on the loop but i cant make javascript read the variable  $('$events[2]') on the php

```
  <script>
var sum = 0;

$('$events[2]').text(function(i, v) {
  sum += parseFloat(v.replace(',', ''));
});

$('.result').text('Result : ' + sum);

</script>
    <?php

    echo "<td class='tb1'>{$events[0]}</td></div>";  //foto
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<div class='w_promotora_images'>{$events[7]}</td></div>";  //foto
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<div class='w_promotora_images'>{$events[3]}</td></div>";  //data
    echo "<td class=''>{$events[2]}</td>";  //nome
    echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[4]}</td>";  //evento
    echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[5]}</td>"; //horario
    echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[6]}</td>"; //obs
    echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[10]}</td>";  //horas
    echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[9]}</td>";  //valor hora
    echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[1]}</td>"; //Props
     echo "<td ><div class='{$events[2]}'> {$events[8]}</td></div>"; //t parcial
    echo "<td class=''><div class='result'>  </div> </td></tr>"; 
}?>


</table>
```

Comment: And what's in `$events[2]`? PHP has some handy methods to sum arrays and such.

Comment: The code makes no sence! Where does the loop start and end. I assume you are in a loop. The total should really be presented after the loop has finished and there should not be a RESULT-TOTAL on every line of a table surely. Look again and then show us some code that makes sence. Also there appears to be no reson to do anything in javascript, it can all be done in PHP before the page is sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variable is in php, javascript will not be able to parse it. You must output the var in php :

```
$('.<?= $events[2] ?>').text(function(i, v) {
    sum += parseFloat(v.replace(',', ''));
});
```

I also add the "." for if you don't add it, jquery will not know that you are fetching an element by its class name.

Comment: didnt work :( my events[2] is an class name like .1234

Comment: what is the result of the source code with the javascript generated ?

Comment: i think it works but some how just not in my loop .. :/

Comment: Inspect the code source of the generated page, what is the class of the div and is it the same ad the jquery selector generated ? You can paste the outputed result to help us debug this

Comment: the variable is passing ... my troble is that the results should loop and the code be reused in the loop..but maybe javascript dont work that way

Comment: my javascript runs only once.. i need the variable to loop